# Найти все ключи в мапе golang

Tags: golang

```
map[string]interface{}
```

Вопрос в заголовке собственно, есть варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через `range`:

```golang
keys := make([]string, 0, len(m))
for k := range m {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/p_U23SM7Di1.